# Sapphire r7 250 driver for ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, 14.04

I have spent the last few hours searching and trying to install a driver for my Sapphire r7 250x GPU. Perhaps I am going about it the wrong way and I may just need to understand how to install drivers for Ubuntu.

My computer hardware:

MB : MSI 970A-G46

CPU : AMD FX 8320

GPU : Sapphire r7 250

RAM : ADATA DDR3 8gb 1800

SSD : ADATA SP900

Just to help any confusion on the GPU here is the webpage : http://www.sapphiretech.com/presentation/product/?cid=1&gid=3&sgid=1226&pid=2028&psn=&lid=1&leg=0

Comment: Did it ultimately work out through the answer? I am looking into the same model family

Answer (score 2):

I think that the easiest way is:

1. open `System Settings`
2. choose `Software Sources`
3. go to the last tab `Additional Drivers`
4. choose the driver to install (the `FGLRX` one, not the `post-release updates`)
5. press `Activate`

Then, put your password and that's it! Better restart your computer to enable the new driver.

Images:

for steps - [1,2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ho8PE.png)

for steps - [3,4,5](http://u.jimdo.com/www59/o/sdcc8e67e188f864a/img/i38b581e84534a760/1397816647/std/ubuntu-14-04-lts-additional-drivers.png)

Comment: Has it been confirmed to work for this card model?